# CSS media: how to run the media code only if scroll bar appears (or how to imitate with JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

How can I use CSS @media to imitate javaScript for the this condition below?

For instance, I want to run the code inside @media only when the image's height is longer than window's height, or in other words, when only the right scroll bar appears because the image height is too long.

```
.img-container {
    text-align: center;
}

@media (min-height: 60em) {
    .img-container {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        border: 4px solid green;
    }

    .img-container img{
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

so if I have this image in my html,

```
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x850"> <-- a long image height so run the code inside @media
    </div>
```

but if I have this below instead in my HTML,

```
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x450"> <-- don't run the code inside @media
    </div>
```

In javascript, if you detect the image height is longer than the screen height, then you run the code to scale down the image, while if it detects the image height is smaller than the screen height, then do nothing

Is it possible with css @media?

This is what I get at the moment:

[image]

Comment: What is exactly that you want? A CSS selector that detects whenever a scrollbar appears?

Comment: `A CSS selector that detects whenever a scrollbar appears? ` - Yes if that is possible.

Comment: So, if you got to the point that you can use JavaScript to detect it, why not just toggle a class on an element (e.g. the `body`) and use that class in your selector? On the other hand, if you just want your image to be smaller than the screen height, you could use `max-height` with `vh`.

Comment: @xpy `you could use max-height with vh.` how? I have `height: 100vh;` in my code already, haven't I?

Comment: Giving it `max-height:100vh` by default and not in the media query, the `.img-container` will never get to the point to be bigger in height than the vieport height.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer I am looking for:

```
.img-container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.img-container img{
    max-height:100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```